# Unwatch all files that start with certain text in file name/title

Tags: git, gitignore

I'm trying to unwatch all files in my Git repository whose file names start with 'form.' For example: 'form1.cfm, form2.cfm, form3.cfm,' which are all throughout my repository in several different levels of directories. This following command has worked for unwatching entire directories, but it's not working in what I'm doing now.

git rm --cached -r *form.cfm

When I execute that command, it just removes/unwatches the first form*.cfm that it bumps into -- not ALL of the matches throughout the file system.

Any advice on how I can ignore file that start with a string and that sit throughout the whole repository? Thank you!

Comment: `form*.cfm` != `*form.cfm`...

Comment: I'm puzzled why the OP used the term "unwatched" here. This is `git rm` which removes files from the system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like:

```
git rm --cached `find . -iname "*form*.cfm"`
```

The `find` will return all the `form*.cfm` in your repo, then just issue a `git rm --cached` to remove the results of `find` from git index.

I tested it with up to 4-level of nested folders:

```
$ tree .
.
├── form1.cfm
└── subfolder1
    ├── form2.cfm
    └── subfolder2
        ├── form3.cfm
        └── subfloder3
            └── form4.cfm
```

Comment: Beautiful solution. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @AlexMacArthur Glad to help. Please consider marking the answer as accepted when you next get the chance. You may have to wait for 15 minutes after the question is posted, before you can accept an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I just created two files in my repository's root called `form1.cfm` and `form2.cfm`, and committed them to the repository. Then I ran:

```
git rm --cached -r form*.cfm
```

and the output says it rm'd both files.

However, I just tried a second attempt, this time also creating a `form3.cfm` in a sub-directory, and it only removed `form1.cfm` and `form2.cfm`. To remove this file also I had to run:

```
git rm --cached -r */form*.cfm
```

Comment: Gotcha -- that works for me as well, but since it only moves down a level where files are affected, it's not ideal. Doesn't affect the whole file system tree recursively. Regardless, good to know something like this might work for some other task. Thanks for the help!